# Couchdb complex query

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have documents with the following structure:

```
exampleDoc: {
    _id: 1,
    type: 'payments',
    date: '06-01-2015',
    userId: 2,
    categoryId: 3,
    amount: 20.49
}
```

I would like to perform the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM payments
WHERE userId IN (1,2,3)
AND categoryId IN (4, 5, 6, 8)
ORDER BY date;
```

How can I do this in NoSQL (CouchDB) ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a design document that indexes on `[userId, categoryId]`:

```
// check out pouchdb-upsert plugin for putIfNotExists
db.putIfNotExists({
  _id: '_design/my_index',
  views: {
    my_index: {
      map: function (doc) {
        emit([doc.userId, doc.categoryId]);
      }.toString()
    }
  }
});
```

Then do a `keys` query with all the `[userId, categoryId]` pairs you want to fetch:

```
db.query('my_index', {
  include_docs: true,
  keys: [
    [1, 4],
    [2, 4],
    [3, 4],
    [1, 5],
    [2, 5],
    [3, 5],
    // etc.
  ]
});
```

By the way, this will be a bit simpler when the [pouchdb-find](http://nolanlawson.github.io/pouchdb-find/) plugin is finished, and you can use the `$in` operator and `$and` operator. :)

Comment: Thx for your reply! And what about sorting by date? Is it possible without the pouchdb-find plugin?

Comment: I've just realized that you are the developer of the pouchdb-find project. :) When can we expect the $in operator support? Many thanks!

Comment: Sorting by date can be done by saving it as a string, e.g. `new Date().toISOString()`. As for `$in`, it will be implemented faster if somebody submits a pull request. :D